# Fixed div on top and bottom

Tags: html, css

<3..just need some help on my page..how do i see all my data if i have a fixed div on top and on the bottom of my page properly. the bottom part is not showing properly specially when i re size the height of the page..  [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/k9Lae/)

```
<div id="page-container" class="">

     <!------------ content ------------>
     <div id="content" class="">

                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="topbox"> 
                <img id="user_image" class="user_image" src="" width="45" height="45"/>
                <span class="nickname" id="nickname"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="message" id="message_container">
                    <div class="messagechat">
                    <ul id="message_area">   
                        somelong data here
                    </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="chatbox">
                    <a href="#" class="pixbtn alignleft"></a>
                    <div class="chat alignleft">
                    <input type="text" name="user" class="text" id="input_area">
                    </div>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="sendbtn alignright" id="button_send"></a>
                </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i corrected you jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/c26zd/2/

If you need some margin between the grey background (top and bottom) and your content, just add for example

```
#content {
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Comment: can i ask you something? i got a problem with my js..my scrollTop is not working. i have a time interval that adds data inside message_area . this one is not working anymore `$('#message_container').scrollTop($('#message_container')[0].scrollHeight);` :(

Comment: Can you please update your jsfiddle, so i can have your current version with javascript ?

Comment: It's the body element who have the scrollbar in your example. @see : http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ when it's another element

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is that you can control height of page with jQuery, in other words when height of page is less than for example 200px both of divs(top and bottom) be minimize(collapse), now you should define mouseover event for both of them that when mouse is over it be initial size(expand) So in this state data will show better even when page height is minimum  , 
you should check height in resize event

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  //do something
});
```